# Xorg consuming 1.1GB, is it a leak?

Tags: linux, xorg, virtual-memory, out-of-memory, memory-leaks

I am facing a problem wherein Xorg starts to consume more and more memory
and finally eats up the whole swap space. As shown below, Xorg's virtual
memory is about 1.1GB. My system runs only one GTK application "main_app"
and I do not have Gnome, I just have IceWM installed. When this scenario 
happens, the system crawls and only a reboot is the way to recover.

```
top - 00:01:09 up 24 days,  6:51,  6 users,  load average: 6.89, 3.63, 2.76
Tasks: 126 total,   1 running, 123 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.0%us,  3.4%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 95.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    505644k total,   442536k used,    63108k free,     1424k buffers
Swap:  2095096k total,  1246372k used,   848724k free,    16400k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1598 root      19  -1 1145m  39m 1308 S    0  8.0 375:06.84 Xorg
 2293 root      20   0  100m 6876 3932 S    2  1.4 747:08.62 main_app
  514 root      20   0 53460  324  140 S    0  0.1  70:38.16 net.agent
 1998 root      20   0 53460  368  140 S    0  0.1  70:40.18 net.agent
23787 root      20   0 53460 9980  196 D    1  2.0   0:00.21 net.agent
23801 root      20   0 53460 9248  196 D    1  1.8   0:00.19 net.agent
 1343 root      20   0 28472  804  564 S    0  0.2   0:03.88 rsyslogd
 3179 root      20   0 23712  180  136 S    0  0.0   0:15.82 MSPAgent
```

As seen below, the /proc/pid/smaps shows that the xorg's heap has all of the 1.1GB.

```
08231000-4da43000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
Size:            1138760 kB
Rss:               35444 kB
Pss:               35444 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:      1476 kB
Private_Dirty:     33968 kB
Referenced:        26436 kB
Swap:            1103276 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

I ran xrestop, but I see that "main_app" is not the culprit.

```
xrestop - Display: :0.0
          Monitoring 9 clients. XErrors: 0
          Pixmaps:    1465K total, Other:      35K total, All:    1500K total

res-base Wins  GCs Fnts Pxms Misc   Pxm mem  Other   Total   PID Identifier
0e00000     7   30    2    8   27     1378K      3K   1381K  2293 main_app
0c00000    67    8    1   38  840       87K     22K    109K   ?   <unknown>
0800000     2    7    6    1   22        0B      6K      6K  1647 uxterm
0000000     1    0    2    0   36        0B      2K      2K   ?   <unknown>
0a00000     2    1    0    0    1        0B     96B     96B   ?   <unknown>
1000000     1    1    0    0    0        0B     48B     48B   ?   xrestop
0400000     1    1    0    0    0        0B     48B     48B   ?   <unknown>
0600000     0    1    0    0    0        0B     24B     24B   ?   <unknown>
0200000     0    1    0    0    0        0B     24B     24B   ?   <unknown>
```

I am not sure why xorg keeps growing. Please give me some pointers on where and
what to look for.

I am on Debian Linux:
debian:~# uname -a
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 21:36:00 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
debian:~#

Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz

Following is the pmap output for the xorg process. Interestingly, the total is 1.1GB, however, the individual entries do not add up to it.

```
debian:~# pmap -x 1598 | more
1598:   /usr/bin/X :0 -br -nocursor -auth /tmp/serverauth.O1gWpWvWuP
Address   Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
08048000       0     404       0 r-x--  Xorg
081e3000       0      24      12 rw---  Xorg
081ef000       0      40      24 rw---    [ anon ]
08231000       0   36188   35232 rw---    [ anon ]
b5422000       0    1892    1888 rw---    [ anon ]
b59a1000       0     384       0 rw-s-    [ shmid=0x520000 ]
b5bd6000       0       0       0 rw---    [ anon ]
b5e85000       0       0       0 r-x--  libexpat.so.1.5.2
b5ea9000       0       0       0 rw---  libexpat.so.1.5.2
b5eab000       0       0       0 r-x--  evdev_drv.so
b5eb3000       0       0       0 rw---  evdev_drv.so
b5eb4000       0       0       0 r-x--  swrast_dri.so
b60c8000       0       0       0 rw---  swrast_dri.so
b60cd000       0    1876    1876 rw---    [ anon ]
b6f83000       0    3072       0 rw-s-  fb0
b7283000       0       8       0 r-x--  libshadow.so
b7288000       0       4       4 rw---  libshadow.so
b7289000       0      56       0 r-x--  libfb.so
b72a6000       0       4       4 rw---  libfb.so
b72a7000       0       0       0 r-x--  libfbdevhw.so
b72ab000       0       0       0 rw---  libfbdevhw.so
b72ac000       0       4       0 r-x--  fbdev_drv.so
b72b0000       0       4       0 rw---  fbdev_drv.so
b72b1000       0       0       0 r-x--  librecord.so
b72b7000       0       0       0 rw---  librecord.so
b72b8000       0      12       0 r-x--  libglx.so
b7307000       0       8       0 rw---  libglx.so
b730a000       0      12       0 r-x--  libselinux.so.1
b7323000       0       0       0 r----  libselinux.so.1
b7324000       0       0       0 rw---  libselinux.so.1
b7325000       0       0       0 r-x--  libextmod.so
b7341000       0       4       4 rw---  libextmod.so
b7343000       0       0       0 r-x--  libdrm.so.2.4.0
b734c000       0       0       0 rw---  libdrm.so.2.4.0
b734d000       0       0       0 r-x--  libdri.so
b7355000       0       0       0 rw---  libdri.so
b7356000       0       0       0 r-x--  libgcc_s.so.1
b7373000       0       0       0 rw---  libgcc_s.so.1
b7374000       0       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
b7376000       0       0       0 r-x--  libgpg-error.so.0.4.0
b7379000       0       0       0 rw---  libgpg-error.so.0.4.0
b737a000       0       0       0 r-x--  libfontenc.so.1.0.0
b737f000       0       0       0 rw---  libfontenc.so.1.0.0
b7380000       0       0       0 r-x--  libbz2.so.1.0.4
b7390000       0       0       0 rw---  libbz2.so.1.0.4
b7391000       0       0       0 r-x--  libfreetype.so.6.6.0
b7404000       0       0       0 rw---  libfreetype.so.6.6.0
b7408000       0       0       0 r-x--  libz.so.1.2.3.4
b741b000       0       0       0 rw---  libz.so.1.2.3.4
b741c000       0       0       0 rw---    [ anon ]
b741d000       0     128       0 r-x--  libc-2.11.2.so
b755d000       0       4       0 r----  libc-2.11.2.so
b755f000       0       4       0 rw---  libc-2.11.2.so
b7560000       0       8       4 rw---    [ anon ]
b7563000       0       8       0 r-x--  librt-2.11.2.so
b756a000       0       4       0 r----  librt-2.11.2.so
b756b000       0       0       0 rw---  librt-2.11.2.so
b756c000       0       4       0 r-x--  libm-2.11.2.so
b7590000       0       0       0 r----  libm-2.11.2.so
b7591000       0       0       0 rw---  libm-2.11.2.so
b7592000       0       0       0 r-x--  libaudit.so.0.0.0
b75a9000       0       4       0 r----  libaudit.so.0.0.0
b75aa000       0       0       0 rw---  libaudit.so.0.0.0
b75ab000       0       0       0 r-x--  libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
b761c000       0       8       4 rw---  libgcrypt.so.11.5.3
b761f000       0       0       0 r-x--  libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
b7623000       0       0       0 rw---  libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
b7624000       0       0       0 rw---    [ anon ]
b7625000       0      72       0 r-x--  libpixman-1.so.0.16.4
b767c000       0       8       0 rw---  libpixman-1.so.0.16.4
b767e000       0       0       0 r-x--  libXau.so.6.0.0
b7680000       0       0       0 rw---  libXau.so.6.0.0
b7681000       0       8       0 r-x--  libXfont.so.1.4.1
b76b5000       0       0       0 rw---  libXfont.so.1.4.1
b76b7000       0      12       0 r-x--  libpthread-2.11.2.so
b76cc000       0       4       0 r----  libpthread-2.11.2.so
b76cd000       0       0       0 rw---  libpthread-2.11.2.so
b76ce000       0       0       0 rw---    [ anon ]
b76d0000       0       4       0 r-x--  libdl-2.11.2.so
b76d2000       0       4       0 r----  libdl-2.11.2.so
b76d3000       0       0       0 rw---  libdl-2.11.2.so
b76d4000       0       4       0 rw---    [ anon ]
b76d5000       0       0       0 r-x--  libpciaccess.so.0.10.8
b76dc000       0       0       0 rw---  libpciaccess.so.0.10.8
b76dd000       0       4       0 r-x--  libudev.so.0.9.3
b76e9000       0       0       0 r----  libudev.so.0.9.3
b76ea000       0       0       0 rw---  libudev.so.0.9.3
b76eb000       0       0       0 r-x--  libdri2.so
b76ed000       0       0       0 rw---  libdri2.so
b76ee000       0      16       0 r-x--  libdbe.so
b76f2000       0       4       0 rw---  libdbe.so
b76f3000       0       4       0 rw---    [ anon ]
b76f6000       0       4       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
b76f7000       0       8       0 r-x--  ld-2.11.2.so
b7712000       0       0       0 r----  ld-2.11.2.so
b7713000       0       0       0 rw---  ld-2.11.2.so
bfcb7000       0      16      16 rw---    [ stack ]
-------- ------- ------- ------- -------
total kB 1197560       -       -       -
debian:~#
```

pmap -d shows the 1.1GB mapped against an anonymous map.

```
debian:~# pmap -d 1598 | more
1598:   /usr/bin/X :0 -br -nocursor -auth /tmp/serverauth.O1gWpWvWuP
Address   Kbytes Mode  Offset           Device    Mapping
08048000    1644 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00001 Xorg
081e3000      48 rw--- 000000000019b000 008:00001 Xorg
081ef000      44 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
08231000 1164236 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
b5422000    3752 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
b59a1000     384 rw-s- 0000000000000000 000:00004   [ shmid=0x520000 ]
```

I need a way now to identify the owner of address 08231000.

The Controller is given below..

```
debian:~# lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
debian:~#
```

debian:~#

Modules loaded by Xorg are as below..

```
debian:~# grep -i "Loading" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
(II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
(II) Loading extension DRI2
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
(II) Loading extension SELinux
(II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
(II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
(II) Loading extension DPMS
(II) Loading extension XVideo
(II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
(II) Loading extension X-Resource
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
(II) Loading extension GLX
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
(II) Loading extension RECORD
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
(II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfbdevhw.so
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Loading sub module "shadow"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
debian:~#


debian:~# /usr/bin/Xorg -version

X.Org X Server 1.7.7
Release Date: 2010-05-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.32.29-dsa-ia32 i686 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 21:36:00 UTC 2011 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686 root=/dev/sda1 nomodeset
Build Date: 19 February 2011  02:37:36PM
xorg-server 2:1.7.7-13 (Cyril Brulebois <kibi@debian.org>)
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
debian:~#
```

Comment: The growth in xorg memory has been very gradual in the order of steps of few KBs every few mins and in about 20 days, it has reached 1.1 GB.

Comment: Xorg seems to consuming only 39MB (the RSS value). For example, consider my current top virtual memory processes: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9370980/ I wouldn't say Clementine music player is consuming 2.7 GB of memory.

Comment: But the size says 1.1GB??
Size:            1138760 kB

Comment: I tried killing my "main_app" to see if the 1.1GB held by xorg is relieved, but in vain. Only a reboot of the system is the choice. After a reboot, the problem resurfaces in a week's time or even lesser time.

Comment: What is your Systems actual RAM Amount?

Comment: @eyoung - The top output shows the RAM size. It is 512MB RAM.

Comment: Added the pmap entry to the description.

Comment: To know what's causing this memory leak may be quite a challenge. One thing you could do is to just "look" at the contents. Chances are small it'll clearly indicate the problem but I don't know much else. Fire up gdb using `gdb /usr/bin/Xorg 1598` where `1598` is the pid. In gdb type `x /500xc 0xNNNNN` where `NNNNN` is the address of the memory region you want to inspect. Notice the `0x` in front of the address, that's required. `500xc` means show 500 bytes in hex and in char. Who knows you can see some data that rings a bell. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but, unfortunately on the target system, we do not package gdb. I am trying to setup a new system with gdb and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think that the issue is your App.  The issue is the amount of RAM.  When the System Runs out of RAM, it starts using the Swap as RAM on Disk, and the actual RAM needs to be freed.  Increase the amount of RAM to the maximum, and the issue should get better.

Comment: We found the issue. It was caused due to an xorg setting "nocursor". After we removed this setting, the leak vanished. When we upgraded to the latest GTK/GDK, the leak is not found even with "nocursor" setting. Thanks to all for the suggestions. We can consider this closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I use VirtualBox after version 5.0. The Xorg  process memory will increase slowly but steadily to 6G.

I disabled `mit-shm` option in `xorg.conf` to solve the problem. You can add the following options:

```
Section "Extensions"
    Option "MIT-SHM" "disable" 
EndSection
```